# Is it possible to use functional interface in collection filtering in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections

The following code compiles:

```
val collection = listOf("a", "b")
val filter = { x: String -> x.isEmpty() }
collection.filter(filter)
```

Is it possible to define the filter using a function interface?

For example the following code doesn't compile:

```
fun interface MyFilter {
    fun execute(string: String): Boolean
}
```

and

```
val filter = MyFilter { x -> x.isEmpty() }
```

gives a compilation error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
(TypeVariable(T)) → Boolean
Found:
MyFilter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inherit `MyFilter` from `(String) -> Boolean`

```
fun interface MyFilter : (String) -> Boolean

fun main() {
    val collection = listOf("a", "b")
    val filter = MyFilter { x -> x.isEmpty() }
    val newCollection = collection.filter(filter)
}
```

With your custom method:

```
fun interface MyFilter : (String) -> Boolean {
    override operator fun invoke(p1: String): Boolean = execute(p1)
    fun execute(param: String): Boolean
}
```

But it works only with `jvmTarget = 1.8 (or higher)` and `-Xjvm-default=all`

Comment: The only downside of this approach is that I cannot name the method in the interface. I.e. when I implement the interface I have to override the method named `invoke`

Comment: That worked, sad that I cannot upvote the answer two times. Good job! (ofc that gets too verbose on the interface level so I would rather go with the default names in the implementation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **member reference** operator `::` to pass the function of interface by reference:

```
val collection = listOf("a", "b")
val filter = MyFilter { x -> x.isEmpty() }
collection.filter(filter::execute)

fun interface MyFilter {
    fun execute(string: String): Boolean
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's a bit verbose (i mean the ::execute part) but works

Comment: Yes, but I think there is no other way of doing that for now.

Comment: Java's functional interfaces are arguably a poor substitute for first-class functions; Kotlin has the latter, and so doesn't have to make too many concessions to the former.